# Why does't bibliography show up in my tex document?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, bibdesk

I try to include bibliography in my tex file, seemingly do everything according to the instructions but it doesn't show up. I use bibdesk. Included all possible packages.
Here is the tex code.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cite}
\begin{document}

\doublespace

Background

The market of structured financial products, primarily for retail investors, has been growing rapidly around the world for more than 20 years. They come in many forms, but share some common characteristics. The payoffs represent combinations of payoffs of several primary securities, such as options, equities, equity indices, and fixed income securities. Structured products are normally issued by financial institutions, which provide the possibility of redeeming the securities over their lifetimes. The redeeming procedures are necessary because the issuance volume of the instruments is too small to create a continuous market unless the issuer provides liquidity. Short-selling of structured products is impossible. The also carry the credit risk of the issuing organization, because normally they are traded outside of derivative exchanges. The primary clients are small investors, who are not able to replicate the payoff by themselves . 

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{Thesis}

\end{document}
```

And this is the bib file.

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: There seem to be no `\cite` instructions in the body of the document. If you simply want all entries in `Thesis.bib` to be included, issue the instruction `\nocite{*}`.

Comment: Incidentally, don't load *both* the `cite` and `natbib` packages.

Comment: Miko, thank you very much for your response. 
Even when I use the \cite command, the citation appears as question marks, and the bibliography doesn't show up at all.
Tried the different variations of packages as well..

Comment: @Aliya You have to run `pdflatex` -> `bibtex` -> `pdflatex` -> `pdflatex`.

Comment: @karkoeller, I am sorry, how exactly do I run bibtex?

Comment: @karlkoeller, I figured it out, it actually worked! thanks a lot!

Comment: probably more than you want to know about getting a bibliography and citations to appear: [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63875/579) (potential duplicate)